# Subversion (20014)Internal error: database is locked on NFS

Tags: svn

i have subversion setup using apache and DAV. OS is RHEL 4. Repository is created on NFS server mounted on this machine.

when i try to access this repository i get following error in apache logs

(20014)Internal error: database is locked
Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #200030]
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #200030]
The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001]

i did 'chmod' on that mounted partition but problem still persists.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

just solved,

Tried mounting again with nolock,rw option.

also started nfslock service on nfs server

thanks anyway

Comment: Beware of corruption.  It is recommended to use the lock.  Check out http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#nfs